# What's the meaning of the default output of manage.py runserver?

Tags: django, django-dev-server

What's the meaning of the default output of manage.py runserver?
Can't find any documentation on it:

```
[25/Jan/2013 07:45:59] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 149
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I've marked up the default output to help explain its meaning:

```
([25/Jan/2013 07:45:59]) ("GET / HTTP/1.1") (200) (149)

(Datetime request was sent) (telnet/netcat-style plaintext request string) (HTTP status code) (bytes sent as response)
```

All these can be confirmed in your favorite browsers dev console.

Comment: It would be nice if you could post a link to where you've got your answer.

Comment: Found it myself by poking around the source a while ago.