# where does this specific log output from django runserver come from

Tags: python, django, logging

I am learning about logging in python, so I am trying to find out where in the source code is the portion to format the line when you get this specific output: `"GET /dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 200 249176`? Also, what does 249176 mean?

I do not have a problem, and this question is to satisfy my curiosity.

I am really looking for the formatter for this logrecord. I also do not see what loghandler this is coming from (perhaps this is not comming from the logging module at all, and it is just a print command). I searched the source code and could not find where this is coming from, and would like to have a link to the source.

Here is what happens when I run my code.

```
September 05, 2013 - 05:38:50
Django version 1.5.1, using settings 'dapi.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[05/Sep/2013 05:38:57] "GET /dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 200 249176
[05/Sep/2013 05:38:58] "GET /static/plugins/uniform/css/uniform.default.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[05/Sep/2013 05:38:58] "GET /static/plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

Comment: Note: this is "logging for web servers" rather than "logging in Python" - it relates to logging requests to a web server, rather than more generalised logging of events in a program.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This number is the response content length, in other words: number of bytes sent.

This output basically comes from [wsgiref](http://docs.python.org/2/library/wsgiref.html#module-wsgiref)'s [simple_server](http://docs.python.org/2/library/wsgiref.html#module-wsgiref.simple_server) (and it is based on [BaseHTTPServer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html#module-BaseHTTPServer)) that is django's `class WSGIRequestHandler` as the follows ([source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/86f4459f9e3c035ec96578617605e93234bf2700/django/core/servers/basehttp.py#L108)).

```
$ cat django/core/servers/basehttp.py

   ... ignored here ...

class WSGIRequestHandler(simple_server.WSGIRequestHandler):

    def log_message(self, format, *args):
        
        ...... the access log comes here ......

        # sys.stderr.write(msg)
        # level(format, *args, extra=extra)
```

[log_request()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html#BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.log_request) function is actually logging the code and content size under the hood:

> log_request([code[, size]])
>
> Logs an accepted (successful) request.
> code should specify the numeric HTTP code associated with the
> response. If a size of the response is available, then it should be
> passed as the size parameter.

If you are interested, take a look at `BaseHTTPServer` pypy realization: https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/9d88b4875d6e/lib-python/2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py

See also:

- [What's the meaning of the default output of manage.py runserver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523143/whats-the-meaning-of-the-default-output-of-manage-py-runserver)