# Log response time in Django views

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

In my view, I am logging to a file using logger.info(message)

The message is a string that must contain the HTTP status and how long it took to handle the request.

i can't find request-response time in HttpResponse().

What suprises me is that django.server logs the time. How did they do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The time taken isn't tracked. The number at the end of the line is the size of the response in bytes.

[What's the meaning of the default output of manage.py runserver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523143/whats-the-meaning-of-the-default-output-of-manage-py-runserver)